# Rails - jquery-html5-upload?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins, ruby-on-rails-3

Has anyone been able to get the jquery-html5-upload plugin to work with Rails 3 + PaperClip + S3? Know of any tutorials?

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-html5-upload/

Thanks

Comment: I didn't but I made with with uploadify, code here: https://github.com/apneadiving/Pic-upload---Crop-in-Ajax

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

https://github.com/stakach/Resumable-Uploads